# Fixing AddressSanitizer: strcpy-param-overlap with memmove?

Tags: c, strcpy, address-sanitizer, memmove

I am poking around in an old & quite buggy C program. When compiled with `gcc -fsanitize=address` I got this error while running the program itself:

```
==635==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: strcpy-param-overlap: memory ranges [0x7f37e8cfd5b5,0x7f37e8cfd5b8) and [0x7f37e8cfd5b5, 0x7f37e8cfd5b8) overlap
    #0 0x7f390c3a8552 in __interceptor_strcpy /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_interceptors.cc:429
    #1 0x56488e5c1a08 in backupExon src/BackupGenes.c:72
    #2 0x56488e5c2df1 in backupGene src/BackupGenes.c:134
    #3 0x56488e5c426e in BackupArrayD src/BackupGenes.c:227
    #4 0x56488e5c0bb1 in main src/geneid.c:583
    #5 0x7f390b6bfee2 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x26ee2)
    #6 0x56488e5bf46d in _start (/home/darked89/proj_soft/geneidc/crg_github/geneidc/bin/geneid+0x1c46d)

0x7f37e8cfd5b5 is located 3874229 bytes inside of 37337552-byte region [0x7f37e894b800,0x7f37eace71d0)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7f390c41bce8 in __interceptor_calloc /build/gcc/src/gcc/libsanitizer/asan/asan_malloc_linux.cc:153
    #1 0x56488e618728 in RequestMemoryDumpster src/RequestMemory.c:801
    #2 0x56488e5bfcea in main src/geneid.c:305
    #3 0x7f390b6bfee2 in __libc_start_main (/usr/lib/libc.so.6+0x26ee2)
```

The error was caused by this line:

```
/* backupExon src/BackupGenes.c:65 */
strcpy(d->dumpSites[d->ndumpSites].subtype, E->Acceptor->subtype);
```

I have replaced it with:

```
memmove(d->dumpSites[d->ndumpSites].subtype, E->Acceptor->subtype, 
strlen(d->dumpSites[d->ndumpSites].subtype));
```

The error went away and the program output produced with 2 different data inputs is identical to the results obtained before the change. BTW, more of strcpy bugs remain further down in the source. I need a confirmation that this is the way to fix it.

The issue & the rest of the code is here:
https://github.com/darked89/geneidc/issues/2

Comment: `[0x7fd8e204c5b5,0x7fd8e204c5b8) and [0x7fd8e204c5b5, 0x7fd8e204c5b8)` - these are the same addresses! Are you copying something to itself?

Comment: @KamilCuk pretty sure OP is already aware of that.

Comment: @KamilCuk I am trying to refactor old code written long time ago by others. Rewriting it from scratch without the big cleanup is not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `E->Acceptor->subtype` is at least as long as `d->dumpSites[d->ndumpSites].subtype` <s>then there's no problem. You might want to check that first if you didn't already.</s> **Actually**, you need a +1 to also copy the string terminator (`\0`), thanks [@R..](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379897/r) for spotting it.

Your previous code was making a different assumption: it was assuming that `d->dumpSites[d->ndumpSites].subtype` was at least as long as `E->Acceptor->subtype` (the opposite basically).

The *real* equivalent would be:

```
memmove(
    d->dumpSites[d->ndumpSites].subtype,
    E->Acceptor->subtype,
    strlen(E->Acceptor->subtype) + 1
);
```

This is the correct way to fix the code to allow overlapping.

Comment: You need a +1 on the result of `strlen` in order for `memmove` to match [the intended behavior of] the original `strcpy` call.

Comment: @R.. ah, sneaky terminator. Thank you.